# How to create test doubles with Sinon that prevents execution of the actual function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am doing javascript **unit** testing with Mocha and Sinon. I want to test whether under certain circumstances, a certain method is called.

However, so far I couldn't manage **only** to test if the method was called. To make it clearer, I want a fake method to replace the actual method, because I don't want to simulate my whole application state to make this simple test pass.

This is my actual test code:

```
it('calls the handleResults method when its model syncs', function () {
  var spy = sinon.stub( this.appview, 'handleResults' ); 
  this.appview.model.fetch();
  server.requests[0].respond( 200,
                   { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                   JSON.stringify( [ { id: "casa", text: "Something" } ] )
  );
  spy.should.have.been.called;
});
```

The real `this.appview.handleResults` method is being called, while I would want to call a fake version which does nothing else than checking whether it was called or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is handleResults a method directly on appView?

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `handleResults`? You must make sure it's going through the same path which assigns the stub in the original method's place.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are very clear that by using `stub`, the original function will be replaced by mock and will not be called:

> As spies, stubs can be either anonymous, or wrap existing functions.
>   When wrapping an existing function with a stub, the original function
>   is not called.

and

> **var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");**
>
> Replaces object.method with a
>   stub function. The original function can be restored by calling
>   `object.method.restore();` (`or stub.restore();`). An exception is thrown
>   if the property is not already a function, to help avoid typos when
>   stubbing methods.